# I can’t locally launch the streamlit app through jupyter notebook, it showed runtimeerror

Tags: python, anaconda, webserver, streamlit

I am new to using the Streamlit app. I used jupyternotebook to locally run the first app using Streamlit. Below is my code:

```
import streamlit as st

#writing simple text 
st.text("Hello")
```

Then, I run the command below in anaconda command prompt.

```
streamlit run C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py
```

Then, I got the popup window with error message as showed below.

```
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 647, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 493, in init_kernel
    shell_stream = ZMQStream(self.shell_socket)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.io_loop = io_loop or IOLoop.current()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 130, in current
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 263, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\webapp\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
```

Below is how the web browser shows.
[image]

How do I resolve this issue? Can I actually run the Streamlit app through the Jupyternotebook?

Thanks for any suggestions you may provide.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have the **ipykernel_launcher.py** file in **site-packages** dir? Move **ipykernel_launcher.py** to your **webapp** dir and try running it from there lets see. If you still get the same error massage, press **ctrl + left-click** on the directory which has the **events.py** right before the last error message to open it and you can show what you got in there. Maybe you need to modify some line of code there.

Comment: You shouldn't be involving Jupyter notebook to run Streamlit. (Note it isn't even listed under the 'Compatible with' section at https://streamlit.io/ .) Also see [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/running-streamlit-in-a-jupyter-cell/584/3) in regards to the last question in your post. You want to save that code you have in your first code block using a coding text editor and save it is`MyApp.py` & then point streamlit at that file, like the animation that plays at the top of https://streamlit.io/ . (Jupyter does have a text editor in it that you could write the `MyApp.py` with but ...

Comment: <continuing> ... easier to think about all this not involving Jupyter since you seem a little confused.) Probably looking into other examples of resources describing how to run your first streamlit app may be advisable.

Comment: To be complete...There are several solutions to make web applications and dashboards from Jupyter notebooks. [Voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the one best supported by the Jupyter community at present.  ----- Someone did make a converter for Streamlit, too, see [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/jupyter-notebooks-to-streamlit-app/1880/4).

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out a basic [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN4DaSAZel4) for locally launching Streamlit as I was new to it. I will also take a look on Voila as another choice for making web app.